# Set letter width to canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can someone explain to me if it possible to set letter width in  canvas element. I have a font where the letters have a different width and I want to set it to predfined width for all letters?

I have a clock where the leters are jumping around and dont look nice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get so called monospace letters.

1. Use a [Monospace font](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace).
2. Use a font feature called [Tabular Figures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/proportional-vs-tabular-figures).

Not all fonts support font features. And not all ways to specify fonts allow the selection of a font feature. In CSS it is possible with the [`tnum`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) option:

```
font-feature-settings: "tnum";
```

In the HTML canvas, you have to use the [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace) API.